# Outputting a condition I didn't mean to get, probably code blocks are not managed properly

Tags: java, eclipse, input, output, codeblocks

New to Java, having hard time with the blocks, the output should be only "Error invalid numbers" when inputting sum = 9 , examGrade = 105 and average = 105.

Output is now :

"Error invalid numbers"

100

100.00

It's somehow gets to the else condition , didn't succeed to manage it, thank you for help in advance :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int examGrade = 0, sum;
    double average = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Please enter your Exam Grade");
    examGrade = input.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Please enter your homework average");
    average = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.println("Please enter number of exercise");
    sum = input.nextInt();
    
    if (sum > 8 || examGrade > 100 || average > 100) {
        System.out.println("Error invaild numbers");
    }
    
    if (sum <= 4) {
        System.out.println("Your Final grade is zero");
    }
    
    if (sum == 5 || sum == 6) {
        if (examGrade >= 55) {
            System.out.println(examGrade*0.8 + average*0.2);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(examGrade);
    }
    
    if (sum == 7 || sum == 8) {
        if(examGrade <= 54) {
            if(average >= 80) {
                System.out.println(examGrade*0.75 + average*0.25);
            }
            else if(average < 80) {
                System.out.println(examGrade*0.8 + average*0.2);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(examGrade*0.7 + average*0.3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it not get to the else condition? The sum is neither 5 nor 6.

Comment: the else is on the   if (examGrade >= 55)  condition inside same indentation

Comment: seems like it's working like you said not sure why, still need help on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to not do all the other checks if you have an "invalid numbers" condition. To do that, you need to wrap all of them into an else like this:

```
if (sum > 8 || examGrade > 100 || average > 100 ) {
    System.out.println("Error invaild numbers");
} else {
    if (sum <= 4 ) {
        System.out.println("Your Final grade is zero");
    }
    // and so on with all the other ifs
} // finish the "not invalid" block
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate, it worked, one thing still causes problems                                              if (sum ==5 || sum ==6 ) {
    if (examGrade >= 55) {
            System.out.println(examGrade*0.8 + average*0.2);
    }
}
    else {
        System.out.println(examGrade);
   }

Comment: on this code it's still gets to the else and prints it even when im inputting sum == 8, seems like the else is working on the sum not on the examgrade like I want it to be (tried to indent it to the same line)